# Where can you view the android source code for the Toolbar widget?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

For both the support version and the Android-L version, I am not able to find the source code for the Toolbar class.

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-l-preview_r2/core/java/android/widget/

and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/android-l-preview_r2/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/

Comment: If you will downvote, please leave a comment stating why.

Comment: One of the flaws of this site I fear.. I guess it does resemble the society at large quite well. Hope you have a thick skin..

Comment: I decompiled the support jar and came up with this: http://pastebin.com/pXR3pnHt . The L version should be up soon as they're just loading the 5.0 source now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/lollipop-release/core/java/android/widget/Toolbar.java) is the source code for the `Toolbar`

EDIT:

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/lollipop-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.java) is the AppCompat `Toolbar`